# How to dynamically add multiple vector layers to a layer group in ol6?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I want to add layers to a layergroup dynamically on a button click.
I have added an OSM layer

```
var map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      title: 'OSM',
      source: new OSM(),
      opacity: 0.5,
    })
  ]
  });
  
  
  //--On button click--
  var yearcmpGrp = new LayerGroup({
      title: 'Year Comparison',
      layers: []
  });
  map.addLayer(yearcmpGrp); //this add a new layergroup
    
    for(var i=fromyr;i<=toyear;i++){
       var sampledata = data;
       var samplevectorlyr = new VectorLayer({
          title:i,
          source: new VectorSource({
            features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(sampledata, {
                dataProjection: 'EPSG:32643',
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:32643',
            }),
          }),
          style: new Style({
            image: new Circle({
                radius: 7,
                fill: new Fill({color: colorpick[i]}),
                stroke: new Stroke({
                  color: [255,0,0], width: 2
                })
              })
          }),
          opacity: 0.5,
        });
         //map.addLayer(samplevectorlyr); //this works fine & add a new layer outside layer group
         map.getLayerGroup(yearcmpGrp).addLayer(samplevectorlyr); //This don't work !!
    }
```

I want to add multiple layers to layergroup in the for loop.  **map.getLayerGroup(yearcmpGrp).addLayer(samplevectorlyr)** is not working

Comment: `map.getLayerGroup()` only returns the map's base layer group.  To add to an known layer group push to its layer collection
`yearcmpGrp.getLayers().push(samplevectorlyr);`

Comment: it worked. how can I remove that layergroup before another button click ? map.removeLayer(yearcmpGrp); is not working. how to use pop()

Comment: This worked for removing layer if (mapp.getLayers().getLength() > 1)  mapp.getLayers().pop(); From your another answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306935/remove-delete-a-layer-or-layergroup-with-mouse-click :-) you are superb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked

`yearcmpGrp.getLayers().push(samplevectorlyr);`

Thanks @Mike. I am posting as an answer bcz it might help somebody.